# Alignment of horizontal dropdown menu using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a dropdown menu that aligns horizontally to work and having some issues with alignments.

Here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jqf66dbp/

I've basically added the following changes to the css for the dropdown

```
  .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 15px;
    min-width: 500px;
  }

  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    right: inherit;
  }
```

Basically when you click thru each menu item, the dropdown box shifts to the right. Is there a way to make it so that it's stuck to the same position as the first menu item?

My second issue that i'm trying to solve are the items within the dropdown. For my fiddle example I made one item longer than the rest "Update Collaborate" You will notice that this item shifts all other items around and messes up the alignment. How can I make all the items align more nicely and have "Update Collaborate" in one line.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated fiddle for your first problem. You can adjust the size of the dropbox in the below CSS class i have made it 100%.

Updated Fiddle:- 
    https://jsfiddle.net/jqf66dbp/3/

```
.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 15px;
    /* min-width: 500px; */
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 48px;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left:0px;
}
```

Could you please give more details on the second problem ? Because i don't see any problem after the above css change